# Is it possible to have emails at a registered domain without hosting?

Tags: email, dns

The hosting for my website will expire at the end of this month.  I don't really wish to stay with my current host – their interface stinks and I don't use the hosting part of the service, anyway.

I'd like to keep my email address there, though – I fully understand that without hosting, I won't be able to keep email on the server (as there would simply be no server to keep it on).  Before I can decide on how to move forward with my domain, I need to know:

> Can I configure my DNS record such that emails sent to foo@domain.com are redirected to bar@gmail.com?

Comment: No, you cant. If you want to use their mail service, you need to renew your hosting with them. Or you can migrate your email service to Gmail, but as I know Gmail is not free anymore. If you dont like hosting with them, you can migrate your hosting to other hosting provider, like asphostportal.com. Their hosting plan comes wtih email account.

Comment: @DouglasThomas I think you misunderstand. I'm not looking to have distinct email addresses. I don't need a place to store the email; gmail will be that (which is still free, unless you're talking about Google Apps). Frankly I know it's possible because I'm doing it right now with my registrar.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you can't. While you can point the MX record to google's mail server it will get rejected since Google doesn't not recognize the domain. You can host your email using Google's Apps, its used to be free but its $50/year now. Other email hosting service will also work but I don't know if there is any free ones available.

You may also consider moving your domain registration elsewhere, some domain registration company, like 1and1, offers free email hosting service and forwarding with domain purchase so you don't need separate web hosting for your email.

Another way is to get a cheap VPS server(as low as $5-$10/year), setup web server, email server etc.. and do everything yourself.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "Google doesn't recognize the domain"?

Comment: By setting MX record the email will be sent to google, but google wouldn't accept them unless you have Google Apps setup.

Comment: Isn't Google Apps something you set up with a hosted solution?

Comment: Google apps is more like a cloud solution. A VPS is a hosted solution.

Comment: And check with your current domain registration company they might offer free email hosting/forwarding as well.

Comment: Well, Google is definitely accepting emails sent to addresses at my domain…

Answer (score 0):

Namecheap has email forwarding for domains without hosting. Im guessing other domain sites will as well.

Cheak out their page about it - https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/308/2214/how-to-set-up-free-email-forwarding

> Our free Email Forwarding feature allows you to create personalized
> email addresses for a domain and forward emails to other email
> addresses of your choice. This service is available for all domains
> pointed to our BasicDNS, BackupDNS (a legacy option), PremiumDNS or
> FreeDNS systems.

Also check out - https://improvmx.com

Their free tier says - “Send mail as” from Gmail